# Modal Message Box Threading Issue

Tags: c#, winforms, modal-dialog, messagebox

I'm trying to make a message box modal but I'm running into threading issues.

I have a class like this:

```
public static class DisplayMessage()
{
    public static void ErrorMessage(string errorMessage)
    {
         MessageBox.Show(errorMessage, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
    //other similar methods
}
```

So I want the message box to be modal to the main form. MessageBox.Show is overloaded so that you can specify an **IWin32Window**. So I tried using .ActiveForm but I get this:

> Cross-thread operation not valid: Control accessed from a thread other
>   than the thread it was created on.

Comment: How are you trying to display the MessageBox - From a background / worker thread ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
    public static void ErrorMessage( Form Parent, string errorMessage )
    {
        if ( Parent != null && Parent.InvokeRequired )
            Parent.Invoke( (Action)(() => MessageBox.Show( errorMessage, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error )) );
        else
            MessageBox.Show( errorMessage, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error );
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do this is like this:

When you start you instance of object save current Dispatcher

```
Dispatcher m_dispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;
```

Then when you have to call something use delegate

```
m_dispatcher.Invoke((Action)delegate()
{
   MessageBox.Show(Application.Current.MainWindow, exception.Message, "Fatal Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
});
```